# Как сделать запрос в AlaSql по дате?

Tags: google-apps-script, alasql

Пишу Google script. Мне нужно отсортировать строки таблицы и записать отсортированные. Для достижения целей использую библиотеку [AlaSql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql). Пытаюсь отсортировать по условию даты. Уже неделю не могу найти решения. Вот код запроса:

```
var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, CAST(Col15 AS date) from ? WHERE Col15 > '2019-01-01' ";
```

Это не работает.
Вот код целиком

```
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id_spreadsheet"); // получаем таблицу по ее id
  var sheet = file.getSheetByName('РЕЕСТР2'); //  - имя листа в реестре
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data_sheet = range.getValues();
  var sheet_2 =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AlaSql");
  var sql = "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col8, CAST(Col15 AS date) from ? WHERE Col15 > '2019-01-01' "; // строка запроса
  var data = getAlaSql(sql, data_sheet); // вызов функции AlaSql
try 
  {
    Logger.log("data.length = " + data.length);
    Logger.log("data[0].length = " + data[0].length);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    Browser.msgBox("Не найдено ни одной строки");
  }

  sheet_2.clearContents(); // очистка данных
  removeEmptyRows(sheet_2); // Вызов функции удаления строк лишних

  sheet_2.getRange(1, 1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // запись результата на лист. data.length - длинна строк,data[0].length - длинна столбцов
```

Читал уже очень много информации. 
Испробовал следующие варианты альтернативные

1. Элемент списка

   [Вариант1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51327982/using-bound-google-scripts-to-generate-a-query-object/51328419#51328419)
2. Элемент списка

   [Method4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56737713/fastest-way-to-search-for-a-row-in-a-large-google-sheet-using-in-google-apps-scr/56737759#56737759)
3. Элемент списка

   [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Результат такой же как в AlaSql. Вся проблема в фильтре по дате.

Изначально логика работы была основана на формуле [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=ru)

```
= query( main_data_sheet ;"select B, D, H, count(I) where  (O is not null and O > date 
'"&TEXT($B$5;"yyyy-mm-dd") &"' and O < date '"&TEXT($B$6;"yyyy-mm-dd") &"') and 
(U = '"&$A$3&"') and (R = '"&$B$8&"' or R = '"&$B$9&"' or
 R = '"&$B$10&"' or R = '"&$B$11&"' or R = '"&$B$12&"') 
group by B,D,H  label B '', D '', H '', count(I) ''  ";0)
```

Где ячейка B8 = дата в формате 01.01.2019. И это работает.

Я перепробовал различные варианты написания запроса в скрипте. Ничего не подходит. Скриншот ниже.
[image: Различные варианты запроса]

Проблема решена. Спасибо большое **@contributorpw**. 
Гугл таблицу со скриптом можно открыть по [ссылке](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z0aXNhsqfjwkcp1E2fY4bfkV-9dcfKO1rwFwMp7abkM/edit?usp=sharing)
Скопируйте ее себе нажав **Файл - создать копию**

Comment: А как вы подключаете AlaSQL?

Comment: Я просто добавил файлы библиотеки в скрипт. [ссылка](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BrZydeCxJAjtP5xQA-g8FbFv1J29L6Uzd1ZKGbfVubc/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Тупой сайт не дает редактировать комментарий спустя 5 мин. 
@contributorpw Я просто добавил файлы библиотеки в скрипт. [ссылка](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BrZydeCxJAjtP5xQA-g8FbFv1J29L6Uzd1ZKGbfVubc/edit#gid=0) как в этом примере. Файлы #Sql , #AlaSql , #Sheets

Comment: Я просил, потому что поддерживаю простенький порт AlaSQL для Google Apps Script https://github.com/oshliaer/alasqlgs

Comment: Да, теперь вижу, что от вашей моя библиотека alasql отличается. Вот шаблон, от куда я брал все файлы  #Sql , #AlaSql , #Sheets. [Шаблон таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BrZydeCxJAjtP5xQA-g8FbFv1J29L6Uzd1ZKGbfVubc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @contributorpw то есть я могу подключить вашу библиотеку alasql и пользоваться полноценно? Я даже не знал, что бывают разные редакции alasql. А в чем собственно отличия от [официальной](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)?

Comment: Никаких отличий нет. Просто добавлена обертка для ленивой загрузки. И весь код выделен в библиотеку Google Apps Script.

Comment: @contributorpw  Просто в той библиотеке, которую я использую, в описаниях обращения к столбцам происходят по ColN,а у вас в примере обращение как к массиву MATRIX [N].  Прошу понять и простить, я новичок в javascripts

Comment: Ничего страшного. Я представляю, как можно запутаться. Использование директивы `MATRIX` оправдано в тех случаях, когда данные после выборки необходимо сразу вернуть в Таблицу. В остальном разницы нет. Если вы приведете пример своей Таблицы в более упрощенном виде, то я покажу на примере, как решить вашу задачу.

Comment: `Col[N]` - это особенность вашего дистрибутива. Посмотрите там код, который преобразовывает запросы.

Comment: @contributorpw спасибо, что помогаете решить задачу. Я подготовил таблицу гугл и открыл ее для всех [ссылка](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z0aXNhsqfjwkcp1E2fY4bfkV-9dcfKO1rwFwMp7abkM/edit?usp=sharing). Так же ее добавлю в описание поста. В таблице два листа. С одного берем данные, в другой пишем. По датам никак не хочет работать. Я еще не пробовал вашу библиотеку подключить. Мне кажется ваше решение куда красивее, с подключением библиотеки. Буду его тестировать.

Comment: Добавил решение. Определил, почему у вас не работает. В файл добавил сравнение запросов `AlaSQL` и `QUERY`

Comment: @contributorpw Спасибо огромнейшее!  Очень благодарю. Но скажите пожалуйста, я не могу запустить функции запросов, пишет что не найдена функция **fromColNota** `TypeError: Не удается обнаружить функцию fromColNota в объекте [object Object]. (строка 7, файл AlaSQLGS_example)` Честное слово, я ничего не правил, не удалял :)

Comment: Эту версию я еще не публиковал. Хм, похоже, что я вам подключил dev-версию. Сейчас попарвлю в файле.

Comment: @contributorpw огромное спасибо Вам! Все работает! Супер!

Comment: Стоит отметить ответ как "лучший".

Comment: @contributorpw Скажите пожалуйста, а мне чтобы дальше использовать вашу библиотеку, стоит оставить режим разработчика включенным?

Comment: Нет, вашего кода достаточно для текущей. Просто в новой версии будет метод `AlaSQLGS.fromColNota(query)`, который заменит одну из ваших функций. Т.е. ничего не изменится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я мапю дату в стринги или нумберы.

В примере ниже первая колонка - колонка дат.

```
function slicer(range) {
  var data = range;
  data.forEach(mapDtoN_);
  var query = 'SELECT MATRIX [0], [1], [2] FROM ? ';
  query += 'WHERE [0] + [1] IN (SELECT MAX([0]) + [1] FROM ? GROUP BY [1])';
  var res = alasql(query, [data, data], function(d){
    return d.forEach(mapNtoD_);
  });
  return res;
}

function mapDtoN_(row){
  row[0] = row[0].getTime ? row[0].getTime() : 0;
}

function mapNtoD_(row){
  row[0] = new Date(row[0]);
}
```

К примеру, выбрать все, которые меньше заданной даты

```
  var data = range;
  var date = new Date().getTime();
  data.forEach(mapDtoN_);
  var query = 'SELECT MATRIX [0], [1], [2] FROM ? WHERE [0] < ?';
  var res = alasql(query, [data, date], function(d){
    return d.forEach(mapNtoD_);
  });
  return res;
```

Для вашего примера все оказалось еще проще. Вот полный листинг рабочей программы

```
/* global AlaSQLGS */
/* exported myFunction2 */
function myFunction2() {
  var query =
    "select MATRIX Col1,Col2,Col4,Col8,Col15 from ? where Col15>=DATE('20190525')";
  query = AlaSQLGS.fromColNota(query);

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('SOURCE_FOR_AlaSql')
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  var header = data.splice(0, 2).map(function(row) {
    return [1, 2, 4, 8, 15].map(function(i) {
      return row[i];
    });
  });

  var alasql = AlaSQLGS.load();

  var res = alasql(query, [data]);

  var values = header.concat(res);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Лист3')
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}
```

Попробовал использовать вашу версию AlaSQL, но результаты не очень, возможно, очень старый код

```
function myFunction3() {
  var query =
    "select MATRIX Col1,Col2,Col4,Col8,Col15 from ? where Col15>=DATE('20190525')";
  query = AlaSQLGS.fromColNota(query);

  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('SOURCE_FOR_AlaSql')
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues();
  var header = data.splice(0, 2).map(function(row) {
    return [1, 2, 4, 8, 15].map(function(i) {
      return row[i];
    });
  });

  var res = getAlaSql(query, data);

  var values = header.concat(res);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Лист3')
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values);
}
```

Вы так же можете подключить свои собственные функции к AlaSQL, но мне как-то для дат не зашло.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но правда, ваш код вызвал у меня больше вопросов,  чем ответов.  Ответьте пожалуйста на них.

Comment: 1) Вы пишете `var query = 'SELECT MATRIX [0], [1], [2] FROM ? WHERE [0] < ?';` -  почему в конце знак вопроса, а не дата для сравнения? По идее тут надо сравнивать с датой какой-то, будь то переменная хранящая дату или строка string с датой типа `WHERE [0] < '01.01.2019'`

Comment: 2) Вы пишите `alasql(query, [data, date], function(d){
    return d.forEach(mapNtoD_);` на сколько я знаю из [справки](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)  функция alasql(request, tables); имеет всего два входных аргумента. Что-то я совсем запутался

Comment: `WHERE [0] < ?` - знак `?` и есть маска для переменной `date`. Переменные в запрос мы добавляем вторым аргументом `alasql(query, args)`

Comment: 3)В строке запроса мне совсем не понятно все ( `alasql(query, [data, data], function(d){
    return d.forEach(mapNtoD_);` - как в alasql передается и главное зачем передается двумерный массив `[data, date]`, где `date` это переменная содержащая сегодняшнюю дату, а `data` содержит массив данных.  Не понятно как работает функция `function(d)`.

Comment: `alasql(query, args, cb, scopes)` как вы можете видеть из сырцов, параметров там предостаточно https://github.com/agershun/alasql/blob/master/dist/alasql.js#L66-L69 Третий аргумент это колбэк. Можно догадаться, когда он будет вызван, а аргументы можно прочитать в логах.

Comment: Выпустил новую версию. Там метода `fromColNota` нет, но вместо него есть другой.

Comment: Спасибо, что уведомили меня. То есть теперь я могу не вызывать посредников, а сразу передать в функцию alasql(#,#) query("string") ?

Comment: query =" строка запроса "; // запрос на поиск строк.  response_alasql = alasql(query, [data]); // ЗАПРОС В БИБЛИОТЕКУ alasql.

Comment: Если вы используетет имена колонок как `ColN`, то вам придется сделать перед `alasql(query)` следующую строку `query = AlaSQLGS.transformQueryColsNotation(query);` В остальном все остается как есть.

Comment: А если не ColN, то по другому как? Можно просто цифровой нумерацией?  0, 1 ... n ? Тогда можно сразу передать строку запроса в alasql(query, [data]); ?

Comment: Не, тогда вам придется писать запрос в виде `select data1.[0] from ? as data1` Это правила AlaSQL